# nock does not intercept follow-up calls when using axios-retry

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs, nock

In short:

- When doing normal calls, `nock` works perfectly
- But when testing a request that triggers `axios-retry`, `nock` fails when the first retry attempt happens (based on logging)

Does nock support retries? If so, how should the test be setup?

Client:

```
const getClient = (authorizationToken: string | undefined, target: ApiParams) =>
  axios.create({
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      ...(!!authorizationToken && { Authorization: `Bearer ${authorizationToken}` }),
      'x-api-key': target.apiKey || 'missing',
    },
    timeout: API_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS,
  });

export const sendRequest = ({ someParams }) => {
  const client = getClient(authorizationToken, target);

  axiosRetry(client, {
    retries: API_MAX_RETRIES,
    retryDelay: (retryCount) => {
      logger.info('retrying request', retryCount);
      return retryCount * API_RETRY_INTERVAL_MS;
    },
    retryCondition: (error) => {
      // There's more in this, but it's not relevant for the question
      return Number(error.response.status) >= 500;
    },
  });
}
```

Simplified implementation that I test:

```
export const upsertExclusionList = async () => {
  const response: ApiClientResult = sendRequest({ someParams });
  if (response.data) {
    return response.data;
  } else {
    throw Error('No data');
  }
}
```

Test that works:

```
  it('processes valid request', async () => {
    nock(serverBaseUrl).put('/exclusion-lists', { some: 'data' }).query({ callerId: 'Tester', role: 'Tester' }).reply(200, { success: true });
    const response: ExclusionList = await upsertExclusionList({ someParams });
    expect(response).toEqual({ some: 'thing' });
  });
```

Test that fails (this test triggers retries):

```
  it('handles a 500 response from the API', async () => {
    nock(serverBaseUrl).put('/exclusion-lists', { some: 'data' }).query({ callerId: 'Tester', role: 'Tester' }).reply(500, { error: 'Some error' });
    await expect(upsertExclusionList({ someParams }).toBeCalledTimes(4);
    // Also did this:
    // await expect(upsertExclusionList({ someParams }).rejects.toEqual('No data');
  });
```

But what happens is I get this:

```
    Attempted to log "Call to put exclusion list API (https://api.example.com/exclusion-lists?callerId=Tester&role=Tester) failed: Nock: No match for request {
      "method": "PUT",
      "url": "https://api.example.com/exclusion-lists?callerId=Tester&role=Tester",
      "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Bearer unit-test",
        "x-api-key": "xxx",
        "user-agent": "axios/1.2.0-alpha.1",
        "content-length": "93",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
      },
      "body": "{\"some\":\"data\"}"
    } (2080 ms)".
```

Versions:

```
node 18.13.0

"axios-retry": "3.3.1",
"nock": "13.3.0",
"jest": "28.1.3",
"ts-jest": "28.0.8",
"typescript": "4.3.5"
```

So, how can I get nock to work with axios-retry?

Answer (score 0):

When you nock a request, the default behavior is that Nock will only intercept a single request. After the single request, that interceptor is removed from the stack so any further requests creates an error. Nock provides two methods to change this behavior.

[`.times()`](https://github.com/nock/nock#repeat-response-n-times), which allows a single interceptor to act on n requests back to back.

[`.persist()`](https://github.com/nock/nock#persist), which will stop an interceptor from removing itself from the stack after being used. Therefore being able to be reused over and over for any request.

If you're writing a test that covers the fault tolerance of your code, say with Axios config that is setup to retry four times. You could create one Nock that returns a 500 three times then returns a 200 on the four attempt. Or mix and match as needed.

```
nock(serverBaseUrl)
  .put('/exclusion-lists', { some: 'data' })
  .reply(500, { error: 'Some error' })
  .times(3)
  .reply(200, { message: 'Success!' });
```